# Is there any way to generate PDF report using PrimeNG TurboTable?

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-turbotable

Is there any way to generate PDF report using [PrimeNG TurboTable](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table) ?

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you can only export data from your table to CSV format :

> DataTable can export its data to CSV format.

http://primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/export

But as you can see on [PrimeNG roadmap](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/wiki/Roadmap), they are working on PDF and XLS format exports.